# How to control the format of an asset's Title

Tags: assets, upload, meta

Is there any way to control the formatting of an asset's title that is created from the filename on upload?

At the moment, if you uploaded a file called `Craft-CMS.pdf` it would create the title as `Craft Cms` - where in most cases I you would expect the uppercase of `CMS` to remain intact.

I see there is a config setting for `filenameWordSeparator`, but nothing related to the pattern used to created the title - is there anyway I'm not seeing to configure this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Craft 2, You can write a [plugin](https://pluginfactory.io/) that listens to the [onBeforeSaveAsset](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#assets-onBeforeSaveAsset) event, and changes the title from the `asset` parameter to whatever you want. Something like:

```
if ($event->params['isNewAsset])
{
    $asset = $event->params['asset']
    $asset->getContent()->title = 'My New Title';
}
```

For Craft 3, you can write a plugin that listens to the [BEFORE_HANDLE_FILE](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-asset.html#EVENT_BEFORE_HANDLE_FILE-detail) event like so:

```
Event::on(Asset::class, Asset::EVENT_BEFORE_HANDLE_FILE, function(AssetEvent $event) {
    $asset = $event->asset;
    $asset->title = 'My New Title';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brad, will look into doing that if I need to! Out of interest, any reason why the default behavior changes the case instead of just replacing separators with spaces?

Comment: Craft title cases (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Case_styles) the file name. Just so happens that doesn't play well with acronyms like "CMS"